# UIPickerView Index as Int

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a picker view. I am able to capture the `String` out of the picker view, but really I just want the `index`. I thought maybe the `selectedRow(InComponent: Int)` would work, but when I try this I get a crash saying

> index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

This is what I am trying

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, InComponent component: Int) {    
    timeFrame = fixedAmountPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: row) 
}
```

What can I do to get the `Index` as an `Int`?

Comment: try with `pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: row)`

Comment: Wouldn't you use the `row` parameter from `pickerView(:didSelectRow:component` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index in different ways:

1. In your `didSelectRow` the `row` parameter is your selected row
2. You can type `fixedAmountPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)` if you´re outside the `didSelectRow`

Answer (score 0):

`pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:)` requires the component (usually 1). If you pass `row` instead of the component number, you will get an error if the row number is greater than the number of components in a pickerView. Think of it as `components` are same as `sections` in a tableView and `rows` are same as `rows`. What you want is what @AgRizzo suggested. Just store the value of `row` in

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, InComponent component: Int) {

    //row will have your index number

}
```